# How to find if a file is binary

Tags: file, haskell, binaryfiles

I am trying to read text of all files in a folder with following code:

```
readALine :: FilePath -> IO ()
readALine fname = do 
  putStr . show $ "Filename: " ++ fname ++ "; "
  fs <- getFileSize fname
  if fs > 0 then do 
      hand <- openFile fname ReadMode
      fline  <- hGetLine hand
      hClose hand
      print $ "First line: " <> fline
  else return ()
```

However, some of these files are binary. How can I find if a given file is binary? I could not find any such function in https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=binary%20file

Thanks for your help.

Edit: By binary I mean the file has unprintable characters. I am not sure of proper term for these files.

I installed UTF8-string and modified the code:

```
readALine :: FilePath -> IO ()
readALine fname = do 
  putStr . show $ "Filename: " ++ fname ++ "; "
  fs <- getFileSize fname
  if fs > 0 then do 
      hand <- openFile fname ReadMode
      fline  <- hGetLine hand
      hClose hand
      if isUTF8Encoded (unpack fline) then do
        print $ "Not binary file."
        print $ "First line: " <> fline
      else return ()
  else return ()
```

Now it works but on encountering a 'binary' executable file (called esync.x), there is error at `hGetLine hand` expression:

```
"Filename: ./esync.x; "firstline2.hs: ./esync.x: hGetLine: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

How can I check about characters from file handle itself?

Comment: What do you mean the file 'is binary'? This is a computer — _every_ file is binary!

Comment: Having unprintable characters. What will be proper term for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: Relevant: [`isUTF8Encoded :: String -> Bool`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=isUTF8Encoded+%3A%3A+String+-%3E+Bool).

Comment: You should open the file in binary mode and read its bytes (`hGetLine` does not seem appropriate), e.g. using bytestrings. Then you can try to decode its contents using ASCII or UTF8 (or what you think it's more appropriate). If the decoding fails, the file was "binary". If it suceeds, you might want to check for non printable chars. It all depends on the precise definition for "binary".

Comment: @AJFarmar IMO, it's very unfortunate that `isUTF8Encoded` works on strings rather than `[Word8]` or bytestrings. (In `Data.ByteString.UTF8` there's no similar function, for some reason.)

Comment: I need to find about character encoding from file handle itself. Pl see the edit in my question above.

Comment: In general, you cannot infer character encoding from the file; you have to *know* how it is encoded.

Comment: So, the only way is to enclose this in try-catch type of block? Could you post an answer.

Comment: The basic answer to this question is that there is no correct way to do what you're asking. A file may *look* as though it contains unprintable characters (by whatever definition), but you may just be using the wrong encoding to decode the contents, with a different encoding it may contain printable characters. But for a given file, it may be possible to find an encoding that only yields printable characters, even if the file isn't meant to contain text. So basically, there is no correct way. You can add heuristics and guesses, but they will never be 100% "correct", 100% of the time.

Comment: For practical purposes, I only want to know if any character in the string is of ASCII or int value > 127. What is best code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of binary is quite vague, but assuming you mean content which is not valid UTF-8 text.

You should use `toString` in `Data.ByteString.UTF8` which replaces non-UTF-8 characters with a replacement character but doesn't fail with an error.

Converting your example to use UTF-8 ByteStrings:

```hs
import Data.Monoid
import System.IO
import System.Directory
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as B

readALine :: FilePath -> IO ()
readALine fname = do
  putStr . show $ "Filename: " ++ fname ++ "; "
  fs <- getFileSize fname
  if fs > 0 then do
      hand <- openFile fname ReadMode
      fline  <- B.hGetLine hand
      hClose hand
      print $ "First line: " <> B.toString fline
  else return ()
```

This code doesn't fail on binary but is not really detecting binary content. If you want to detect binary, look for `B.replacement_char` in your data. To detect non-printable characters, you may look for code points smaller than 32 (space character) as well.